# Delete unmatching objects in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, nested, lodash

I got problem to use the splice method in a generic way in a nested array.
So what I want is to delete objects in "bigArray"s "nestedArray"s if "filterArray" dosen´t have a reference for the object.

I´ve made an example of what I want to do. 
If you guys got a solution on how I can improve it in native javascript or with Lodash feel free to give input. I'm really stuck.

Expected result should be:

```
  sort.unsortedArray = { "bigArray" : [
  {"id": 1, "text" : "This should be visible when done",
    "nestedArray": [
      { "id": 2, "nestedText": "Sort me out!" }
    ]
  },
  { "id": 2, "text" : "This should be visible when done",
    "nestedArray": [
    { "id": 2, "nestedText": "This one should  be visible in the coming array" }
    ]
  }]}
```

Here´s a [codepen](http://codepen.io/Roesler/pen/YWPBVg) for it.

```
 var sort = this;
var init = function(){
  sort.outObjects();
};
sort.filterArray = { "filter" : [
  { "id": 3, "groupId": 1 }, 
  { "id": 2, "groupId": 2 }]};

sort.unsortedArray = { "bigArray" : [
  {"id": 1, "text" : "This should be visible when done",
    "nestedArray": [
      { "id": 1, "nestedText":"Sort this one out!" }, 
      { "id": 2, "nestedText": "Sort me out!" }, 
      { "id": 3, "nestedText": "This one should  be visible in the coming array"}]},

  { "id": 2, "text" : "This should be visible when done",
    "nestedArray": [
      { "id": 1, "nestedText": "Sort me out!" }, 
      { "id": 2, "nestedText": "This one should  be visible in the coming array" }, 
      {"id": 3, "nestedText": "Sort this one out!" }]}
]},

sort.outObjects = function (){

  //Check that we got the objects in same scope
  if(sort.filterArray && sort.unsortedArray){

    //Loop through "bigArray" object
    for( var i = 0; i< sort.unsortedArray.length; i++){

    console.log("sort.unsortedArray.length : ", sort.unsortedArray.length);

      //Loop through each "nestedArray":s objects
      for( var j = 0; j< sort.unsortedArray[i].nestedArray.length; j++){
      console.log("sort.unsortedArray[i].nestedArray.length : ", sort.unsortedArray[i].nestedArray.length);

        //Loop through filterArray object and compare each object in nested array, if they dont match, delete them.

       for( var k = 0; k< sort.filterArray.length; k++){
        console.log("sort.filterArray.length : ", sort.filterArray.length);

        if(sort.filterArray[k].id != sort.unsortedArray[i].nestedArray[j].id){

         //Delete unmatching object from unsortedArray
          sort.unsortedArray[i].nestedArray.splice(j,1);

         console.log("sort.unsortedArray after splice : ", sort.unsortedArray);
       }
      }
    }
  }
  }
  else{
    console.log("Missing connection to object",sort.filterArray, sort.unsortedArray);
  }
}

init();
```

Comment: what do mean with "if "filterArray" dosen´t have a reference for the object" ? `"bigArray"` doesn't have any object with `groupId` property

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, exactly! Thats the problem I'm facing. its only a reference to the bigArray:s objects.

Comment: ok, show how should look the expected result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, good idea! I added the expected result. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could generate an object for faster access and test for the final filtering.

After generating it, you could iterate over the data, check if a change is necessary and apply filtering.

Edit: Proposal for more than one id to keep.

```js
var filterArray = { "filter": [{ "id": 3, "groupId": 1 }, { "id": 2, "groupId": 2 }] },
    unsortedArray = { "bigArray": [{ "id": 1, "text": "This should be visible when done", "nestedArray": [{ "id": 1, "nestedText": "Sort this one out!" }, { "id": 2, "nestedText": "Sort me out!" }, { "id": 3, "nestedText": "This one should  be visible in the coming array" }] }, { "id": 2, "text": "This should be visible when done", "nestedArray": [{ "id": 1, "nestedText": "Sort me out!" }, { "id": 2, "nestedText": "This one should  be visible in the coming array" }, { "id": 3, "nestedText": "Sort this one out!" }] }] },
    filterObject = Object.create(null);

filterArray.filter.forEach(function (a) {
    filterObject[a.groupId] = filterObject[a.groupId] || Object.create(null);
    filterObject[a.groupId][a.id] = true;
});

unsortedArray.bigArray.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.id in filterObject) {
        a.nestedArray = a.nestedArray.filter(function (b) {
            return filterObject[a.id][b.id];
        });
    }
});
console.log(filterObject);
console.log(unsortedArray);
```

Comment: Brb I´ll try! Good suggestion! :)

Comment: @NinaScholz, your result differs from OP's expected result. Consider that

Comment: or the ops result does not match with the given data?

Comment: compare attentively the first `nestedArray` between your result and the OP's result. Attentively ...

Comment: if we treat `filterArray` as a whitelist, then 1.3 and 2.2 should be kept. the result of op shows 1.2 and 2.2.

Comment: yes, if the OP made mistake you should elaborate is that result meant by OP is right/actual or is a mistake

Comment: Intreseting, this also means you have all the values in different scopes instead of the same scope as I did with "this".. ?

Comment: @MichaelR, you can move it in any scope you want. is the result that what you expect?

Comment: @NinaScholz, Yes! It worked on the real solution too!  Nina rocks!!! Thank you big time! :D

Comment: @NinaScholz , only got one problem with this though, that is that this generate a new bigArray object for same groupId and then same nestedObject for every nestedArray object, Here´s a codepen to demonstrate. http://codepen.io/Roesler/pen/YWPBVg

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution;

```js
var fa = { "filter" : [{ "id": 3, "groupId": 1 },{ "id": 2, "groupId": 2 }]},
   usa = { "bigArray" : [{"id": 1, "text" : "This should be visible when done", "nestedArray": [{ "id": 1, "nestedText":"Sort this one out!" },{ "id": 2, "nestedText": "Sort me out!" },{ "id": 3, "nestedText": "This one should  be visible in the coming array"}]},{ "id": 2, "text" : "This should be visible when done","nestedArray": [{ "id": 1, "nestedText": "Sort me out!" },{ "id": 2, "nestedText": "This one should  be visible in the coming array" },{"id": 3, "nestedText": "Sort this one out!" }]}]},
    sa = fa.filter.reduce((p,c) => { var f = p.find(f => f.id == c.groupId);
                                     f && (f.nestedArray = f.nestedArray.reduce((n,o) => o.id == c.id ? n.concat(o) : n,[]));
                                  return p }
                                   ,usa.bigArray);
console.log(sa);
```